# Styling radio button label inside just one table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, label, styling

Here is the thing, I have one table with multiple rows containing radio buttons, i want to achieve this:

When i check a radio button the adjacent label changes color, and all other labels in THAT single row loose the color.

Right now im close but im missing some jquery skills to remove the color properly on other radio buttons of the same row.

Here is the fiddle, worth more than thousand words. Any help is much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/cos33qvk/

Javascript:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    if($('input:radio').is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().find('label i').addClass("on");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('label i').removeClass("on");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
    // remove color properly on other radio buttons
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td label i').removeClass("on");

    // add class for current label
    if ($('input:radio').is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().find('label i').addClass("on");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cos33qvk/2/